# Compare counts from subqueries

Tags: mysql, count, compare, subquery

Is it possible to compare subquery count results somehow like this:

```
SELECT
    c_contact.id,
    c_contact.name,
    c_contact.firstnames,
    c_contact.securityid
FROM c_monitoring 
  JOIN c_contact ON c_contact.securityid = c_monitoring.securityid 
  JOIN c_ln_event_debtor ON c_ln_event_debtor.f_contact = c_contact.id 
  JOIN c_event ON c_event.id = c_ln_event_debtor.f_event
WHERE
  ( 
    SELECT count(c_event.id) 
    FROM c_event 
    WHERE c_event.id = c_ln_event_debtor.f_event
    AND c_event.f_status IN(50,51,52)
  ) = (
    SELECT count(c_event.id)
    FROM c_event
    WHERE c_event.id = c_ln_event_debtor.f_event
  )
GROUP BY
    c_monitoring.securityid
```

I would like to have rows to result set only if all referencing c_event rows have f_status 50 or 51 or 52. I have tried this with no luck.

Comment: Have you tried running this?

Comment: This is certainly wrong, but for your expected result, should rows from c_event and c_ln_event_debtor be related to the current c_monitoring/c_contact?

Comment: Do you really need to do it by COUNTing?   How about WHERE NOT EXISTS ( Select ... WHERE f_status not in (50,51,52))

Comment: @Rachcha Yes i have. Not working.

Comment: @regilero c_monitoring references to c_contact. C_contact refs to c_ln_event_debtor. C_ln_event_debtor refs to c_event

Comment: And why am I getting downvoted here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the `EXISTS` clause for this kind of query. In the below we filter out c_events that have an f_status that isn't 50,51,51:

```
SELECT
    c_contact.id,
    c_contact.name,
    c_contact.firstnames,
    c_contact.securityid
FROM c_monitoring 
  JOIN c_contact ON c_contact.securityid = c_monitoring.securityid 
  JOIN c_ln_event_debtor ON c_ln_event_debtor.f_contact = c_contact.id 
  JOIN c_event ON c_event.id = c_ln_event_debtor.f_contact
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
        FROM c_event 
        WHERE c_event.id = c_ln_event_debtor.f_event
        AND c_event.f_status NOT IN (50,51,52)
    )

GROUP BY
    c_monitoring.securityid
```

If the above still produces unintended results then you can join the EXISTS onto c_ln_event_debtor:

```
SELECT
            c_contact.id,
            c_contact.name,
            c_contact.firstnames,
            c_contact.securityid
        FROM c_monitoring 
          JOIN c_contact ON c_contact.securityid = c_monitoring.securityid 
          JOIN c_ln_event_debtor ON c_ln_event_debtor.f_contact = c_contact.id 
          JOIN c_event ON c_event.id = c_ln_event_debtor.f_event
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
                FROM 
                c_ln_event_debtor d
                JOIN c_event ce ON ce.id = d.f_event
                WHERE d.f_contact = c_contact.id
                AND ce.f_status NOT IN (50,51,52)
            )

        GROUP BY
            c_monitoring.securityid;
```

Edit: I notice the join on c_event uses `c_ln_event_debtor.f_contact` is this intentional?

Comment: Doesn't work. It returns row if there are c_events with other f_statuses than 50,51,52

Comment: @AngularAddict Looking at your query you're joining onto `c_event` using the `f_contact` field. Is that intentional?

Comment: @AngularAddict I've added an alternative which should work if the intention is to exclude all contacts where any c_ln_event_debtor for that contact has an associated event without status 50,51,51.

Comment: Thanks. This second one nails it.